# Can we create single composer file for more then 1 module

Tags: magento2, module, composer

I am creating one module which will contain more then 1 module in it. Is it possible to create single composer file for more then 1 module?

Please let me know is it possible or not. If yes, then it will be more helpful if you can tell me how.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, with the following directory structure:

```
- composer.json
- registration.php
- module1/
- module2/
```

`composer.json` contains the reference to `registration.php` as usual.

In `registration.php` you define the source directories for both modules:

```
<?php
namespace {
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
        \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
        'Company_Module1',
        __DIR__ . '/module1'
    );
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
        \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
        'Company_Module2',
        __DIR__ . '/module2'
    );
}
```

The directories `module1` and `module2` contain the rest of the source files for each module.

Comment: Would this also work modules placed in the "vendor" directory, installed from a custom composer repository?

Comment: Yes, actually this only works for composer installed modules, I assumed you were asking for that. For modules in app/code you need two separate registration.php files

Comment: Should I keep registartion.php, module1 & module2 inside Vendor folder?

Comment: I don't understand the question. If you install the package with composer, all will be placed within the vendor directory and you shouldn't change anything there